# Finding a surjection onto [0,1]

Tags: elementary-set-theory

An exercise I was given read: "Let A be any (possible infinite) set. Argue by contradiction to show that there is no surjection from A to $\{0,1\}^A$. "

Am I right to think this means that the set A is countable and that the exercise is showing that $\{0,1\}^A$ is un-countable or have I missed something?

Comment: The exercise is not excluding uncountable $A=\mathbb R$ for example. It has nothing to do with countable and uncountable in the first instance. Maybe think about a bijection between $\{0,1\}^A$ and the power set $\mathcal P(A)$. What do you know about the cardinalities of $A$ and $\mathcal P(A)$.

Comment: In the case that $A$ is (infinitely) countable, then this result would imply that $\{0,1\}^A$ is uncountable.  However, you are showing something more general.

Comment: Hmm, I don't think I understand what $\{0,1\}^A$ means then. I thought  it was the "destination" interval [0,1] after leaving form A.

Comment: $\{0,1\}^A$ is the set of all functions $f:A\rightarrow \{0,1\}$.

Comment: and {0,1} is the same as the interval [0,1] ?

Comment: $\{0,1\}$ is the set of two elements, namely $0$ and $1$.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. A always has lower cardinality than the power set. I should probably look to modify Cantor's diagonal argument then.

Comment: What does the title have to do with the question?

Comment: nothing if you know what the symbols stand for

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*:

Suppose that $\phi$ is any function from $A$ to $\{0,1\}^A$. Consider $f:A\to\{0,1\}$ defined like this:
$$f(a)=1-\phi(a)(a),\quad\forall a\in A$$

Is there any $a_0\in A$ such that $\phi(a_0)=f$?

Comment: what is $\phi(a)(a)$?